# How exactly does nonlinear quantization in compading help in data compression

Tags: audio, adc, signal-processing

I keep reading that we would need 13 bits to store audio sample with linear quantization but with compading we can get the same "quality" with only 8 bits.

How exactly does nonlinear quanitization help in data compression i.e using 8 bits instead of 13? What is meant by quality in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a citation, quality is most likely the measure of total distortion in the original vs. reproduced signal.

Human hearing occurs on a logarithmic level.  This means humans hear more relative to the other sound 'around' than the absolute sound level.  This is why audio amplifiers are measured in dB (a logarithmic scale).  This means that what sounds to us like close in amplitude may really be a 10x or more change in volume.

To accurately cover all ranges of sound, you need to cover the entire range (of course).  So, if this range is enormous, such as human hearing, you need an enormous amount of precision (#of bits used to store each sample amplitude) to store the data with linear encoding.

If instead, you go to non-linear encoding, you can keep a relatively high quality (lesser than with linear encoding) but achieve a much higher range.

As a numerical example, lets assume the human ear picks up sounds from amplitude of 1 to 100000.

- If we use linear encoding with a delta of '1', we have 100,000 buckets for each sample to go into, and to represent this we need 16 bits to store.
- If we use instead 10 points per power of ten, we would only have 50 buckets, which requires a measly 5 bits to represent.

An easy way to visualize how nonlinear quantization helps is to think of a logarithmic plot.  See the image below:

[image: linear vs. log]

You can see that the linear plot takes quite a bit of range to show.  Supposing the plot went much much higher up, you would need proportionally that many more bits to accurately store with the same precision.  But, if you instead use non-linear quantization to encode the value, you can cover a much larger range with the same # of data points.

The same phenomenon occurs with component sizes!  You will notice the repeating values for each power of 10 increase.  This is for the same reason as well!! It gives relatively high access across all useful ranges of resistances/capacitances, etc, but does so with a relatively small # of total sizes.

[image: stolen from another se.ee answer]

The photo above shows component values and how they are chosen.  For a small # of sizes, you get quite a good range.

This is the same reason that you non-linear quantization helps with audio encoding.

Answer (score 3):

The human ear has a surprisingly large dynamic range.  We can hear very quiet sounds and very loud sounds.  If you have a microphone generating voltages based on the volume of the sound, and then you quantize the voltages, you would need a rather large dynamic range.  According to what you read, it would take 13 bits to make sure that you can properly capture the human ear's ability to detect loud and soft sounds.

However, we can observe that the human ear's sensitivity to volume is not linear.  As we see higher sound pressure levels (SPL) corresponding to louder signals, we find that the human ear is less sensitive.  Thus, if we are hearing a sound whose SPL is 0.006Pa (which is a 50dB sound), a difference in pressure of 0.001Pa is extremely noticeable.  If we're hearing a sound whose SPL is 6.3Pa (110dB), a difference in pressure of 0.001Pa is hardly noticeable at all.

Thus, if we're encoding an audio sample for human consumption, it's wasteful to simply quantize the sound pressure level (which typically corresponds to voltage in the microphone) linearly.  However, if we encode the sample non-linearly, we can provide finer resolution of pressure levels when the sound is quiet, and a coarser resolution of pressure levels when the sound is loud.  Because of the limits of the human ear, the consumers of this audio sample won't notice that loss of resolution as the sound gets loud.  As it turns out, 8 bits can encode sound pretty well for the average consumer of audio, though higher bitrates are common for those who seek higher fidelity sound.

We can't always use these techniques to encode the sound.  Recording studios will often record at a much higher bitrate, such as 16-bit or 24-bit sound and then mix it down to 8-bit later.  They do this because they will process the sound through many filters, and some of those filters can bring out the distortion that arises from a 8-bit nonlinear encoding.  Once they're done running it through the filters, they can downsample it to 8-bit using a common nonlinear function if they wish.